# To the northeast we stand

Tags: riddle

I have a riddle. Problem is I don't know the answer. Whoever answers it right will be awarded best answer. The deadline is the end of the month. If no correct answer is given before then, I will close this question (or ask for it to be closed). Here is the riddle:

> To the Northeast we stand,
>   Ancient natives of the new world,
>   Proud though no longer tall.
>   Worn by age we still watch over the land,
>   Still more noble than our cousin hills,
>   Tell us our name.

> *1 word, no punctuation*

I can input the answer and see if it is right or wrong. But the site has nothing to do with the riddle. It is a random riddle basically.

The answer has nothing to do with religion. It may also have something to do with geography/maps. It is likely talking about the north eastern USA. That is what I know.

Comment: I would have added "Night Watch" in Game of Thrones as the answer but then I read the last sentence. :(

Comment: The riddle suggests more than one of whatever it is. It could be a tribe of people, a forest, or even a mountain range. Or anything with multiple things in it.

Comment: Night Watch also contains many people but it is not a single word (as the question need).

Comment: The Night's Watch also isn't to the north*east*; they're all across the north of Westeros and in the northwest of the known areas of Westeros & Essos.

Comment: aahh...how could i forgot...i saw that map so many times....

Comment: You say you don'the know the answer but based on comments to the answer you do have a way to check answers. Can you provide some context about where you found the riddle? It might provide another clue.

Comment: It wouldn't. The people there who know the answer won't tell but they said that it has nothing to do with the site.

Comment: and who are those people?

Comment: Other members like me. And the admin.

Comment: The site is in closed beta, so you couldn't look around much. A lot of the stuff on there is members only things

Comment: Everything needed is in the riddle, I am told. It likely has something to do with geography.

Comment: Okay this question did me more good than I ever expected. I was at one rep and now I am at 20

Comment: Where did you find this riddle?

Comment: I found it on a site that is called Catisserie. It is in a closed beta state. So even if I were to show you where it is, you wouldn't be able to do much. A lot of the content is members only stuff. The riddles are given once every month.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Thanks to question_asker for improvement in the answer*

Pretty sure the answer is

> Adirondacks. (The Adirondack Mountains)

To the Northeast we stand,
Ancient natives of the new world,

> The Adirondacks are in the northeast of North America.

Proud though no longer tall.
Worn by age we still watch over the land,

> The Adirondacks are one of the oldest extant mountain ranges, which is why they're not terribly high compared to newer mountain ranges like the Himalayas.

Still more noble than our cousin hills,

> Not sure about this one; I *think* this may refer to other remnants of the [Central Pangean Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Pangean_Mountains) such as the Scottish Highlands and the Anti-Atlas range. The Scottish Highlands aren't as high and the Adirondacks and the Anti-Atlas Mountains aren't as well-known as the Adirondacks, at least in Anglophone culture.

Comment: Um, pretty sure that in British literature, art, and culture spanning hundreds of years you'll find many references to the Scottish Highlands.

Comment: @PaulEvans Yeah, I'm really not sure about the interpretation of that line; I edited it to rework my reasoning. It could also reflect an America-centric asker.

Comment: Okay Appalachians didn't work. It is not the answer. Nice try though!

Comment: I thought it was a mountain, but it could also be a tree or a tribe of Indians (native Americans) or something.

Comment: I was thinking "Adirondacks" with the same reasoning you used (and similarly unsure of the "hills" bit)

Comment: @question_asker you, you should try answering the question with that!

Comment: @AChildofGod I assume you got your answer...so maybe edit this answer. Reasons would be same for both the answers.

Comment: @AChildofGod I accepted your edit; if Adirondacks is indeed the answer, go ahead and mark this accepted.

Comment: I think you might be trying to read too much into the last line.  I think "more noble than our cousin hills" is referring to a general class not a specific instance.  It's saying the answer is something more than just hills. aka the answer is a mountain range; not that it's not the most eroded segment of the chain.